# What is the csi driver for google cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, helm

For aws eks service there is helm chart for csi driver to handle volumes.
[aws-ebs-csi-driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver)

What is the alternative for gke, google kubernetes engine?

Please suggest.

Comment: Googling "csi driver gcp" brings me to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/gce-pd-csi-driver.

Comment: That didn;t work as expected or nearby

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what didn't work, and what you expected.